# How much activation energy is required to combust propane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, energy, enthalpy, combustion

According to WolframAlpha, the change in enthalphy in the combustion of propane is -2220 kJ/mol. How do I calculate the activation energy required start the reaction in the first place? Do you use the same principles as when calculating delta H or am I missing something mind bogglingly obvious?

Comment: have a look here http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Kinetics/Modeling_Reaction_Kinetics/Temperature_Dependence_of_Reaction_Rates/The_Arrhenius_Law/Arrhenius_Equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/fuels-ignition-temperatures-d_171.html

The autoignition temperature is an external variable.  It depends upon total pressure and oxygen partial pressure.  For paper it is famously 232.778 C (significant figures aside).